# HTML/CSS Let Images Resize with Div

Tags: html, css

Total noob to HTML/CSS here. I'm having difficulty getting my website to look correctly when the window is resized. This is what happens:

Gross:

[image: Gross]

I set the body background blue. Then the white background is created with two divs (one called "body" the other called "body-text") containing all the body elements, styled as such:

```
.body {
  margin: 35px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  padding-bottom: 50em;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.body-text {
  margin: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

So how can I get the images to stay inside the white div when I resize the screen? I'm sorry if this question has been asked before, I'm not exactly sure how to word this. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here try this code it will make your `DIV` responsive**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>
div{
  margin: auto;
  width: 80%;
  border: 3px solid #73AD21;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color:blue;
}
img{
width:100%;
height:auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<img src="https://images.news18.com/ibnlive/uploads/2021/07/1627377451_nature-1600x900.jpg">
<p>Responsive DIV</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Let me know if this will work for you or you want something else**.

Comment: Ahh, that's beautiful! Thank you!
However, the img style causes all the images to be different sizes, even though I gave them all the same width and height in the <img src> tags. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: can you share a screenshot of the output you want?

Comment: Ahh, nevermind. I was able to achieve the desired output simply by removing height: auto. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding this to your CSS.

```
img {
display: block;
}
.body {
  margin: 35px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  padding-bottom: 50em;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.body-text {
  margin: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work -- perhaps that display is conflicting with other things in my CSS. But I really appreciate your response! It seems all I needed was to specify width 100%

Comment: Good to know that you fixed it. Good luck with the project. :)